# CefSharp get screenshot of a page

Tags: cefsharp

Is it possible to get screenshot of a web page using `CefSharp`? I have found information about `GetImage()` method but it seems to be not supported anymore. Is there any other way? I need to get screenshots from off-screen browser so making screenshot of a screen with browser displayed is not a solution.

Comment: check out http://blog.clicdata.com/2014/02/07/how-to-use-net-webbrowser-to-take-screenshots/

Comment: @RachelGallen thanks, but I need CefSharp, not .NET WebBrowser (actually I tried WebBrowser and managed to get screenshots, but for some reason it crashes the program - even vshost.exe - arbitrary from time to time).

Comment: have you the latest version/ it was updated 2 days ago? I think it was an issue but now it's resolved

Comment: @RachelGallen version of what? CefSharp or WebBrowser?

Comment: @RachelGallen could you please explain more? I updated to the latest prerelease version, but still don't see `GetImage()` method and cannot find any information about how to make a screenshot of a page.

Comment: i don't use it myself but i believe it was listed as an issue and was marked as resolved in the new release. It may be in the updated readme file or release notes

Comment: @RachelGallen maybe you mean something else, not CefSharp? According to https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/releases the latest release was April 16, and it doesn't contain anything similar.

Comment: that's weird because i definitely googled cefsharp last night and the page came up as 'updated 2 days ago' maybe an error on my part sorry. it is listed as an issue though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented this feature in a forked branch https://github.com/ivan-sam/CefSharp. This implementation depends on a another commit that fixes script evaluation bug https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/445 , so please clone or download the whole branch.

I've modified CefSharp.Wpf.Example project and added Snapshot button that makes snapshot of the page and opens an image.

If you need to use this feature in WinForms app you can host WPF control with [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I have already solved the problem by using Awesomium, but I definitely will try your solution next time (because Awesomium isn't ideal too...)